# Clicking class instance affects always the first one, not the clicked one

Tags: javascript

Im sure is a simple one but I cannot figure out how to fix it, this is the code:

```
function something ( id ) {

this.id = id
this.card = document.createElement( "div" );

document.body.appendChild( this.card );

}

something.prototype.click = function () {

   this.card.addEventListener( 'click', ()=> { checkId( this.id ) } );

}

something.prototype.checkId = function ( id ) {
   console.log( id );
}

for ( let i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
   var instance = new something(i);
}
```

If I create 4 "cards" from the class "something" and I click wichever element, the passed id is always the id of the first class ocurrence, so my function won't work.

Any clue? What am I missing here?

// EDIT

I create 5 cards, append them to body. Click the third one for example. Get the first one id.

Comment: Can you create a working code snippet so that we can see what you are actually trying to do? :)

Comment: You just attach in dynamic div element a click Event and call to function then its work.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the cards and omit using the `prototype` construct by doing this:

```js
function something(id) {

  this.id = id
  this.card = document.createElement("div");
  this.card.setAttribute('id', id);
  this.card.setAttribute('class', 'card');
  this.card.addEventListener('click', () => {
    checkId(this.id);
  });
  this.card.innerHTML = `Card: ${this.id}`;

  container.appendChild(this.card);
  
  function checkId(id) {
    console.log(id);
  }

}

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  new something(i);
}
```

```css
#container .card {
  display: inline-box;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 25px;
  margin: 30px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(156,156,156,1);
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

#container .card:hover {
  transform: scale(1.05);
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```